# Not able to parse fields with underscores

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

I have a column name viewed_by on Firebase server

```
Test
  |
  |--viewed_by: 30
```

On the app I have a POJO class which has the member **viewed_by**

**Test.class** has member

```
private int viewed_by;
```

In **onDataChange** function when I receive the data, I get the Test object using the **getValue** function

```
Test t = dataSnapshot.getValue(Test.class);
```

But I get the value as 0 instead of 30.

If I change the field name from **viewed_by** to **viewedBy** (both on server and POJO class), I get the expected value (30)

Is it a parsing issue in getValue function? Or the field name are not supposed to have underscores in the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jus figured it out, had to change the function names as well from **ViewedBy to Viewed_By** for it to work with viewed_by field

```
/**
 *
 * @return
 * The viewed_by
 */
public int getViewed_By() {
    return viewed_by;
}

/**
 *
 * @param viewed_by
 * The viewed_by
 */
public void setViewed_By(int viewed_by) {
    this.viewed_by = viewed_by;
}
```

Comment: Better to switch to GSon or Jackson library to avoid such errors

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just declare the properties like below-using `@PropertyName("property_name")` in your model and use your getter and setter just like you like to do.

```
public class Actor {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "profile_id")
    @PropertyName("profile_id")
    private String profileId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @PropertyName("name")
    private String name;

    @PropertyName("profile_id")
    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    @PropertyName("profile_id")
    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```